# 14.04 login loop; tried suggested solutions but no luck; will work with older linux kernel

Tags: grub2, login

I'm still rather new to Linux. Login loop started earlier this week after an update that required a reboot. I searched here and found suggestions for doing a package repair via "recovery mode" (did not help);reinstalled lightdm (did not help); I've read the bits about Xauthority and chown and I believe I've tried that correctly and file permissions seem to me to be correct.

I login from grub2 (because I have a dual boot). If I use the advanced login and choose the previous kernel, everything works fine.  So 4.2.0.41 works and 4.2.0.42 fails. (so I am currently logged in using 4.2.0.41 to write this).

Does anybody have any suggestions?  I am open to upgrading to 16.04 2LTS (if that helps) but my system won't give me the option for some reason. If I reset the "upgrades" tab to "notify for any version" it offers an upgrade to 15.x but when it's set to "notify for long term versions", nothing is offered.

I have a dell XPS-8900 desktop, dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu with each being loaded on a separate 250 GB SSD, and a 2 TB hard disk

**EDIT** posting from my history.log file

Start-Date: 2016-07-19  07:48:38
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.97'
Install: linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic:amd64 (4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1), libefivar0:amd64 (0.21-1~14.04.2), linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic:amd64 (4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1), mokutil:amd64 (0.3.0-0ubuntu3~14.04.1), linux-headers-4.2.0-42:amd64 (4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1), linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic:amd64 (4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1), linux-signed-image-4.2.0-42-generic:amd64 (4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1)
Upgrade: shim-signed:amd64 (1.9+0.8-0ubuntu2, 1.17~14.04.1+0.8-0ubuntu2), dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5, 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.6), libarchive13:amd64 (3.1.2-7ubuntu2.2, 3.1.2-7ubuntu2.3), linux-generic-lts-wily:amd64 (4.2.0.41.33, 4.2.0.42.34), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 45.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), thunderbird:amd64 (38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 45.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), linux-headers-generic-lts-wily:amd64 (4.2.0.41.33, 4.2.0.42.34), linux-signed-image-generic-lts-wily:amd64 (4.2.0.41.33, 4.2.0.42.34), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 45.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), linux-image-generic-lts-wily:amd64 (4.2.0.41.33, 4.2.0.42.34), thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 45.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), linux-signed-generic-lts-wily:amd64 (4.2.0.41.33, 4.2.0.42.34), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138, 3.13.0-92.139)
End-Date: 2016-07-19  07:49:28

Answer (score 0):

If you know the package (program) that you updated which created the problem (often an ATI/Radeon or Nvidia driver) it is a relatively easy fix. If this is so, then you can return to the previous version of the driver from the working kernel (from which you can boot) which should fix the problem. From the Software Sources window go to the driver tab on the far left and select an earlier version of the driver.
If it was another package and you know the name of the package then you should install Synaptic (you can do so from a terminal with command `sudo apt-get install synaptic`), search for the package within synaptic and select (highlight) it, then click the "Package" option near the top, then click "Force Version..." and select a previous version of the package.  Then you can click "Apply" and once the downgrade of that package is complete, open a terminal and enter `sudo sync` and as soon as it finishes you can reboot your computer and the problem should (or may) be fixed.  This though, is without going through any debugging of the problem to try and correct it without removing or downgrading the version of the package (which can take far longer, but not always).

Hope this is helpful,

David

Comment: Thanks David. You tweaked me to look at the history so I am editing my post to include info from the history.log file. I believe this is the update that caused the problem because the following entry is where I tried "apt-get purge lightdm" to fix things.  As for your suggestion about the drivers tab "on the far left" (did you mean right, or am I in the wrong place?). I don't see where you can see previous drivers etc. Does the history I've added give you any additional insight to the problem?

Comment: I did in fact mean the far Right. Sorry for that.  Your add in states that the updates came from a Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) source, but you made clear that you are using 14.04.  That may be a source of problems. I would edit /etc/apt/sources.list and change everything which says "wily" to "trusty" which is what 14.04 is. You should check the files in the other folder in /etc/apt/ to ensure they are all set for trusty rather than wily. sudo nano /etc/apt/"file name" and add any other folder to the /etc/apt/ chain to move to that folder.

Comment: The 14.04 point releases might actually have "wily" repository info.  Unless you added them yourself, leave them alone.  Can you log into the guest session?  Did you delete the .Xauthority completely to try to fix?

Comment: @monkeyman I see that now. I do run 14.04 and have no idea why "wily" is appearing there.  This update was one of those automatic updates that pop up. I just mention this because I'm a little nervous to start changing things that I don't understand and would like to believe that the auto-updates at least use the correct version.  I'll investigate.  Thank you again

Comment: After correcting the Ubuntu version sources you should then sudo apt-get update  then sudo apt-get upgrade, then sudo apt-get autoremove (or clean up apt after the corrections and updates/upgrade with "Bleachbit as Root").

Comment: @ubfan No, I could not log in as a guest either. As for Xauthority, I tried this "mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak" (but I don't know what I'm doing ... just found that on a forum)

Comment: @monkeyman I checked the sources.list file (in etc/apt) and "wily" does not appear anywhere.  Everything is "trusty"

Comment: The same for the /etc/apt/'s sub-folders (/etc/apt/preferences.d/, /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, /etc/apt/apt.conf.d and any other sub-folders)?  Wily is clearly in there somewhere or else your package manager could not have installed any packages from the wily package set.